# How to use NgFor for a single element

Tags: angular

I have the following component that grabs a response from my service that makes a REST call as follows:

**api.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  url = 'api address';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getContent(){
    return this.http.get(this.url);
}
}
```

The response is return as follows:

```
{
    name: "intro1",
    course-content: "this is the content area"
}
```

**content.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  content;
  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getContent().subscribe((res : any[]) => 
    {console.log(res[0])
    this.content = res[0];
```

) 
      }
    }

Note: Im only pulling a single element [0] from the response, but Im not sure how to properly display the data in the content.component view. The row is logging to the console as required and the content is being displayed in the view, but Im still getting the following error:

```
cannot read property 'course-content' of undefined.
```

In ***'old' AngularJS*** I could reference it in the view with the following:

```
<p>{{content['course-content']}}</p>
```

but Im not how to do the same thing in ***'new' Angular***.

Comment: Is your response meant to be an array? If not, is there any reason why you're treating it as one?

Comment: [This page](https://angular.io/guide/http) will give you exactly what you are looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getContent()` method in `ApiService` is asynchronous (`HTTP GET` call), it means your `content` property will be `undefined` until request has completed.

To avoid accessing `course-content` property of `content` in case `content` is not defined yet, use `ngIf` syntax in template :

```html
<p *ngIf="content">
  {{ content['course-content'] }}
</p>
```

#### Suggestion for some improvment

May I suggest you some improvment by typing your model.

```js
export interface Course {
  name: string,
  course-content: string 
}
```

Then, your service should be like below:

```js
export class ApiService {
  ...

  getContent(): Observable<Course[]> {
    return this.http.get<Course[]>(this.url);
  }
}
```

You can also use the powerful of RxJS and `Observables` directly inside your code:

```js
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  content$: Observable<Course>;

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.content$ = this.api.getContent().pipe(
      map(courses => {
        return (!courses || courses.length === 0) ? null : courses[0]; 
      })
    );
  }
```

In your template :

```html
  <p *ngIf="content$ | async as content">
    {{ content['course-content'] }}
  </p>
```

Comment: He's returning an observable and subscribing to that in .ts, what do you mean until request has completed ??

Comment: I mean HTTP request could take a few milliseconds or seconds or more... so view is calculated before request is completed (response returned), and if content is not null-checked, an error occurs (read property of undefined)

Answer (score 1):

try adding an *ngIf: `<p *ngIf="content">{{content['course-content']}}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

I usually make use of interfaces to easily use JSON objects.

**School.ts**

```
export interface School {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    registrationCodeStudent: string,
    amountOfStudents: number
}
```

**school.service.ts**

```
schoolUrl: string = environment.apiEndpoint + "/school/";
getSchools(): Observable<School[]> {
    return this.http.get<School[]>(this.schoolUrl);
}
```

So now I got myself a list of Schools that I can use in my component.ts or component.html files.

**Random component file**

```
this.schoolService.getSchools().subscribe(schools => {
   this.schools = schools;
}, error => {
   this.handleError(error);
});
```

**Random HTML file**

```
<div *ngFor="let school of schools"(click)="onSchoolSelected(school)">
    <p>{{ school.name }} ({{ school.amountOfStudents }})</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scenario.

If this.content has only one object for every request you can directly write like below

change variable **content** as **content: any = {};**

```
<p>{{ content.coursecontent }}</p>
```

if this.content has more than one element you can write like below:

change variable **content** as **content: any = [ ];**

```
<p *ngFor="let c of content">{{ c.course-content }}</p>
```

hope this works for you.

Comment: What? It's not valid javascript. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghrb1a

Comment: yeah you are right. course-content doesn't work in this situation because of " - ", try "coursecontent" it works.